# 'acces denied' message with next auth with google as a provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next-auth

I m getting an 'acces denied' message with next auth with google as a provider.[image]

I set up the Authorised redirect URIs like this, http://localhost:3001/api/auth/callback/google because I m using oauth and running it on http://localhost:3001, at the point I have to choose a google account this message pops up after I clicked on my google account. I also added 2 google accounts as test users.

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session }) {
      // store the user id from MongoDB to session
      const sessionUser = await User.findOne({ email: session.user.email });
      session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();

      return session;
    },
    async signIn({ profile }) {
      try {
        await connectToDB();

        // check if user already exists
        const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: profile.email });

        // if not, create a new document and save user in MongoDB
        if (!userExists) {
          await User.create({
            email: profile.email,
            username: profile.name.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase(),
            image: profile.picture,
          });
        }

        return true
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error checking if user exists: ", error.message);
        return false
      }
    },
  }
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Comment: Have you tried the following:
- Make sure to add the google account as a test user on the OAuth Consent screen
- Some problem with validation schema in your models conflicting with the google profile

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting access denied is because when the `signIn` callback returns `false`, it will stop the auth flow from going forward and redirect to the error page you're seeing. It's probably happening to you in case use exists and you're returning `false`. You should return a falsy statement from the sign in callback no matter what. Otherwise, you will always be redirected to the error page.

Now, on how to handle the userexists case: you should find ways to work around that, because the sign in callback is very limited on what it can do.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to next.config.js file (it worked for me):

```
experimental: {
serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['mongoose'],
}
```

I also recommend using the next.config.js file of that project as stated in the source code . Link to it :
https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_next_13_ai_prompt_sharing/tree/main

Edit: Another thing you can try (it also helped me): I didn't realise that my IP address is changing , so that I couldn't access the database , so make sure to make the ip address settings in the network access in the mongoDB atlas is set to be from everywhere